# how to capture trace output of flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex3

I have an Air application. It consist of an HTML component. I create a flex application and launch this application in HTML component of Air Application. I am able to capture the trace output of Air application but I can not capture trace output of flex application. As this flex application is launched in Air application's HTML component. I use vizy that output the log prints. How can I capture the trace output of flex web application. Thanks

Comment: So the AIR app has an HTML piece that runs a flex app?

Comment: yes, Air application has a HTML component that load and display flex (web) app.

Comment: You may have to debug them separately. This seems like a cumbersome arrangement.

Comment: If you're using flex, one solution would be to use mx.logging.Log and implement a custom LoggingTarget to save the trace to a file, or show it on screen.

Comment: @jpop can you please share some sample code for this. I am new to flex. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, use mx.logging.Log for debug traces and custom LogTarget to capture them.

It would go something like this. Declare the necessary objects:

```
private var logTarget:MyLogTarget= new MyLogTarget();
private var myLog:ILogger;
```

Set up logging where you initialize the application:

```
myLog=Log.getLogger("MyApp");
Log.addTarget(logTarget);
```

Log stuff:

```
myLog.info("Something something.");
myLog.warn("This is weird!");
myLog.error("This shouldn't happen!");
```

The meat of the solution is the custom log target, MyLogTarget.as:

```
package 
{
    import mx.logging.LogEvent;
    import mx.logging.targets.LineFormattedTarget;

    public class MyLogTarget extends LineFormattedTarget
    {

        public var log:Vector.<String>=new Vector.<String>;

        public function MyLogTarget()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function logEvent(event:LogEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.message);
            log.push(event.message+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This particular implementation just stores all traces in a vector of Strings, but you can modify it to save the log to disk, send it to a service, trace it on screen or whatever works for you.